# Extract Specific Rows and Columns from a DF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the below data frame and I need to figure out how I can filter and only extract the info I need. The DF has groups and users. The A in the DF means the user is a group admin and U means just a normal user in the group.

I need to be able to get a report that shows me if any of the Groups listed in the DF has no admins(A), another report that gives me a list of Groups with no Admins or Users  and finally a list of any users that are not members of any groups.

| Name | Group1 | Group2 | Group3 | Group4 | Group5 | Group6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User1 | A |  | U |  | A |  |
| User2 |  | A | A |  |  | U |
| User3 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| User4 | A | A |  |  | U |  |
| User5 | A |  |  |  |  |  |
| User6 |  | A |  |  |  |  |

I basically need 3 separate reports to come out of this 1 DF.

I have been trying to use Pandas,  melt, dropna and groupby.agg but I am struggling to get the desired outputs.

Comment: It's always best to provide the code you already tried ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) on `Name`, then check boolean conditions aggregated with [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html)/[`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for boolean slicing on the indexes:

```
df2 = df.set_index('Name')

# groups with no admins
df2.columns[~df2.eq('A').any()]
# or
# df2.columns[df2.ne('A').all()]
# ['Group4', 'Group6']

# groups with no user nor admin
df2.columns[df2.isna().all()]
# ['Group4']

# users part of no group
df2.index[df2.isna().all()]
# ['User4']
```

*NB. I am assuming that empty cells have NaNs, if they have empty strings, replace `isna()` by `eq('')`.*

Comment: Thanks for the awesome response. Its working, I'm just trying to figure out how to get all of them sent to Excel now.